# Finding the first Non-Numeric Character in a String

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If I have a cell with a mixture of numeric and non-numeric characters, I can locate the position of the first numeric character with:

```
=MIN(IF(ISERROR(FIND({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0},A1)),"",FIND({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0},A1)))
```

For example:

[image]

How would I find the position of the first non-numeric character?  So if **A1** contained:
1234^H**^G

the formula would return **5**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: (must be entered as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```
{=MATCH(TRUE,ISERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))),0)}
```

[Source](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T010610_Finding_the_First_Non-Digit_in_a_Text_Value.html)

Comment: I get **#N/A** ..................

Comment: It works as an *Array formula* .............Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention (array formula: Ctrl+Shift+Enter)!

Answer (score 0):

Just out of interest I'll drop an answer to an (nearly 10 years) old question. I came across this while browsing and thought I'd add in an alternative based on new dynamic array functionality within ms365:

```
=FIND(LEFT(@TEXTSPLIT(A1,ROW(1:10)-1,,1)),A1)
```

---

Also, for those using the construct given in the original answer; you can use a non-volatile approach dropping `INDIRECT()` and use:

```
{=MATCH(TRUE,ISERROR(--MID(A1,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)),0)}
```