# Finding the first Non-Numeric Character in a String but not excluding decimal denominators

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, string

Building off of this resolved question:
[Finding the first Non-Numeric Character in a String](https://superuser.com/questions/874105/finding-the-first-non-numeric-character-in-a-string/1782129#1782129)

In that question, the OP requested help on an excel formula which would return the position of the first non-numeric character in a string. This in itself is very useful to have and received a very clean solution:

```
{=MATCH(TRUE,ISERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))),0)}
```

The issue is that I'm looking for a variant of this solution, but that would not exclude the decimals- or thousand- denominators `.` and `,`.

I've been looking for an elegant solution for hours, but I haven't quite gotten there yet, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have four approaches:

1. Uses the [CODE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/code-function-c32b692b-2ed0-4a04-bdd9-75640144b928) or [CHAR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/char-function-bbd249c8-b36e-4a91-8017-1c133f9b837a) functions
2. Uses the [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) function
3. Uses a recursive LAMBDA function
4. Appends & prepends digits

### 1.  CODE / CHAR Approach

TRUE finds the first lookup character that isn't in the [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) array, while FALSE finds the first lookup character that is.

###### Example 1   ( CODE / CHAR )

Returns the position of the 1st character in `A1` that does **NOT** match a character in `{","; "."; [0-9]}`

```
# CHAR to CODE version

=XMATCH(TRUE,
   ISERROR(VLOOKUP(
     CODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)),1)),
     VSTACK(44,46,SEQUENCE(10,,48)),1,0)))

# CODE to CHAR version

=XMATCH(TRUE,
   ISERROR(VLOOKUP(
     MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)),1),
     CHAR(VSTACK(44,46,SEQUENCE(10,,48))),1,0)))
```

**<sub>'NOT' a Digit, Comma, or Period (CHAR to CODE)</sub>**
[image]

**<sub>'NOT' a Digit, Comma, or Period (CODE to CHAR)</sub>**
[image]

###### Example 2    ( CODE / CHAR )

Returns the position of the 1st character in `A1` that matches a character in `{[A-Z,a-z]}`

```
# CHAR to CODE version

=XMATCH(FALSE,
   ISERROR(VLOOKUP(
     CODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)),1)),
     VSTACK(SEQUENCE(26,,65),SEQUENCE(26,,97)),1,0)))

# Since the lookup in this instance is not case-sensitive,
# the formula can be simplified further with UPPER (or LOWER)

=XMATCH(FALSE,
   ISERROR(VLOOKUP(
     CODE(UPPER(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)),1))),
     SEQUENCE(26,,65),1,0)))

# CODE to CHAR version

=XMATCH(FALSE,
   ISERROR(VLOOKUP(
     UPPER(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)),1)),
     CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,65)),1,0)))
```

**<sub>'IS' a letter of the Alphabet  (CHAR to CODE)</sub>**
[image]

**<sub>'IS' a letter of the Alphabet (CODE to CHAR)</sub>**
[image]

### Example Character Codes

`CODE("A")=65`   /   `CHAR(65)="A"`

| CHAR | CODE |
| --- | --- |
| , | 44 |
| . | 46 |
| 0-9 | 48-57 `=SEQUENCE(10,,48)` |
| A-Z | 65-90 `=SEQUENCE(26,,65)` |
| a-z | 97-122 `=SEQUENCE(26,,97)` |

### 2.   SUBSTITUTE Approach

Using the [original formula](https://superuser.com/a/874107/) and adding multiple [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) functions to change any periods and commas to digits such as **`0`**.

- The volatile [INDIRECT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) function in the formula was replaced by the [SEQUENCE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90) function: 
  `SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1))`   *instead of*    `ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))`

```
=MATCH(TRUE,ISERROR(VALUE(
   SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
     MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)),1),
     ".",0),",",0))),0)
```

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Character** ---------- | **=SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE(A#),".",0),",",0)** ------------------------------------------- | **=VALUE(B#)** ---------------- |
| `.` | `0` | `0` |
| `7` | `7` | `7` |
| `,` | `0` | `0` |
| `a` | `a` | `#VALUE!` |

### 3.   Recursive LAMBDA Approach

I wrote a named LAMBDA function that calls itself (recursive).  The formula is simple; it tests a string to see if can be coerced to a number but not to a date, if yes, it returns the string, if not, it drops the last character from the string and repeats the process until the string is either empty, or a number is encountered.

This approach will work for many more types of numbers such as negative numbers and scientific notation, I filter for dates and times as it introduces some additional issues. It will also interpret strings-as-numbers in line with your computer's regional settings.

###### Assumptions

This formula relies on the following 2 assumptions:

1. The string in `A1` is composed of a number immediately followed by zero or more "additional characters"
2. The "additional characters" never include a digit as their first or second character.

###### Create Named Formula

I named my formula `_getNum` in Excel's "Name Manager." Customize the name as you wish however keep in mind, since the formula calls itself, the name in the formula needs to match the name under which it is saved.

```
# formula returns the number portion of the string

=LAMBDA(str, IF(OR(str="", AND(
    ISERROR(DATEVALUE(str)),
    NOT(ISERROR(VALUE(str))))),str,
    _getNum(LEFT(str,LEN(str)-1))))
```

Alternatively, this `_getPos` version will return the position of the next character after the number string

```
=LAMBDA(str, IF(str="", "",
  IF(AND(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(str)),
     NOT(ISERROR(VALUE(str))))),LEN(str)+1,
    _getPos(LEFT(str,LEN(str)-1))))
```

Either can be modified depending on your needs or simply adapted in the cell formula.

For example:

1. Return the position of the first character after the number string:

   - `_getPos(A1)`
   - `=LEN(_getNum(A1))+1`
2. Return the number as a string

   - `=_getNum(A1)` or
   - `=LEFT(A1,_getPos(A1)-1)`
3. Return the string that follows the number

   - `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,_getNum(A1),"")`
   - `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)+1-_getPos(A1))`
   - or customize the Named formula

[image]

[image]

[image]

### 4.   Append & Prepend Digits Approach

This approach leverages the fact that commas and periods are valid number separators (North America). `1` is prepended and `000` is appended to all characters prior to testing with the VALUE function.  Please note that [OP commented](https://superuser.com/questions/1782147/finding-the-first-non-numeric-character-in-a-string-but-not-excluding-decimal-de/1782163#comment2783401_1782163) that an earlier version of this formula identified the letter `E` as a valid digit because `1E000` is scientific notation for `1^0` which is equal to `1`.  I expect it has other unforeseen behaviors and I originally removed this approach in favor of the alternatives, but have since restored it as it was the approach of choice for the OP.

```
=LET(str,SUBSTITUTE(A16,"E","F"),
  MATCH(TRUE,ISERROR(VALUE(
     "1"&MID(str,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(str)),1)&"000")),0))
```

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Character** ---------- | **="1"& A# &"000"** ------------------------ | **=VALUE(B#)** --------------- |
| `.` | `"1.000"` | `1` |
| `7` | `"17000"` | `17000` |
| `,` | `"1,000"` | `1000` |
| `a` | `"1a000"` | `#VALUE!` |

---

### Line Breaks in Formulas

I put line breaks in my longer formulas.  This makes them easier for me to read and debug.  They also display better in code blocks when the width is restricted.

Most functions, with a few exceptions, allow *unnecessary* spaces and line breaks without any impact other than visual.  Obviously, spaces and line breaks within strings will become a part of the string

Line breaks are inserted in formulas when editing the formula use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

1. You can paste a formula containing line breaks into Excel's "Formula Bar."
2. If you want to paste it directly into the cell, make sure it is in edit mode, accessed via <kbd>F2</kbd> or by double-clicking the cell.

**<sub>Paste formula containing line breaks to "Formula Bar"</sub>**
[image]

Comment: Your example formulas while nicely displayed aren't copyable since they contain line breaks. Consider always keeping it in one line (if you want it to go on two lines if too long simply put the backticks on the same line as the formula.)

Comment: @YisroelTech they are copyable with the line breaks. [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaS8V.gif)  I use them to make the code easier to read in both my formulas and my answers.  Where line breaks are not supported (rarely, but sometimes), I do not include them. Updating my answer in case anyone else is confused.

Comment: Your suggestion helped me along to find a solution to something I've been looking at for days! Thank you so much!

Just FYI There actually was only one instance where it didn't perform perfectly: If the character following my numbers was an "E" (like for example 5.000EUR); it would register the "E" as a number. 

Reason: for big numbers Excel sometimes uses 5E3-like notation to indicate 5x10 to the power of 3. 
Anyway I fixed that with a substitute.

Thanks again. Your insight was incredible!

Comment: Just for your information, if you want to make this non-volatile (or at least semi-volatile) just use a construct where you'd drop the `INDIRECT()` function alltogether. I suppose something like `=MATCH(TRUE,ISERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1),".",0),",",0))),0)`

Comment: Also, I hope you don't mind some positive criticism, but would this not yield a false positive when you'd have a value like, let's say: `1,111.111.Test`. I've not tested it, but won't you retrieve the position of the uppercase 'T' while in fact you should retrieve the position of the 2nd dot?

Comment: The CODE / CHAR approach makes this more extensible as you can reference range of characters to exclude/include whereas the VALUE() approach is hyper-focused on numbers

Comment: @BlindSpots, yeah, and even then. How strict does OP want's to get? I mean is `001,123` a valid number? In a strict sense, the two leading zero's can't be part of a numerical substring holding the thousand seperator, therefor one *could* potentially say that `001` is the numerical part of this string. I'm just trying to say this question has a high ambiguity =). Nice answer though!

Comment: @BlindSpots why did you remove your original suggestion? That was the one I ended up using and which for me worked perfectly. For anyone else's reference, here it is:

=MATCH(TRUE;ISERROR(VALUE("1"&(MID(A1;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)));1))&"000"));0)

Comment: As my dataset is over 140K lines long and I have to run it multiple times per line, anything that takes more than a few calculations will completely bog down my file. So that's where your excel formula came in to fix my problems. Thanks again

Comment: @DriesVermeulen I have restored the [original solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1782147/finding-the-first-non-numeric-character-in-a-string-but-not-excluding-decimal-de/1782163#1782163:~:text=Append%20%26%20Prepend%20Digits%20Approach) slightly modified to remove the volatile INDIRECT function (reduces recalculation of formulas) and also added in the substitution fix for **"E"** `=LET(str,SUBSTITUTE(A16,"E","F"),MATCH(TRUE,ISERROR(VALUE("1"&MID(str,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(str)),1)&"000")),0))`.